# I want to check the phone contain SD card or not and following method always return true if SD card not available

Tags: android, android-studio

I use the following method to check if phone conatins sd card or not but the issues is always return true if SD card not available please help me .

```
Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

        if(isSDPresent)
        {
          // yes SD-card is present
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SD card available ", 2000).show();
        }
        else
        {
         // Sorry
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SD card not available ", 2000).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns true because `getExternalStorage()` returns virtual SD card in internal memory.

You can use

```
Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) 
     && Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable();
```

to check is SD card removable or not

Comment: Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable() return always false even sd card persent in phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can't check with Android API like Environment.*ExternalStorage* because they refer to the emulated sd card that is part of the data partition (so it will allways be mounted).

You can run "mount" shell command and try to find external sd card mount point, but is vendor (and sometimes device) spesific.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this :

```
File file = new File("/mnt/extSdCard");
     try
     {
     File list[] = file.listFiles();
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yes sdcard is mounted, file count "+list.length, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
     catch(NullPointerException o)
     {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry no sdcard is mounted:", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
```